# How to get password field value in react's material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am not able to access the value of `<TextField />`, if i don't write `<input type='password'/>` then it works fine, but for this i am getting a TypeError,  '**this.refs[this._getRef(...)].getInputNode is not a function**'.

```
 dialogAction(tag,e){

  console.log(this.refs.password);
  console.log(this.refs.password.getValue());
  this.refs.dialog.dismiss();
}

render(){
let self = this;

let row = this.row,col = this.column;
let standardActions = [
  { text: 'Cancel',onTouchTap: this.dialogAction.bind(this,ProductConstants.CANCEL)},
  { text: 'Submit',onTouchTap: this.dialogAction.bind(this,ProductConstants.SUBMIT)}
];

return (
  <div className="ProductRepository">

    <Dialog ref = 'dialog'
      title="Dialog With Standard Actions"
      actions={standardActions}
      actionFocus="submit"
      modal={true}>
      <TextField ref='password'
        hintText="Password"
        floatingLabelText="Password">
        <input type="password" />
      </TextField>
    </Dialog>
    </div> 
    );}

   }
```

image below is the console output of the above code.

[image: console output]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This solved my issue:

```
<TextField ref='password'
    hintText="Password"
    floatingLabelText="Password"
    type="password">
</TextField>
```

After that

```
 this.refs.password.getValue()
```

gives the desired output.

> For React v >= 15.6

```
<TextField ref={x => this.password = x}
    hintText="Password"
    floatingLabelText="Password"
    type="password">
</TextField>
```

in inputHandler function

```
this.password.value
```

Answer (score 19):

For material 1.0 and react 16.1.1

Use inputRef

```
  <TextField autoFocus={true} inputRef={el => this.fv = el} 
        placeholder="Required" size="30"></TextField >
```

To read the value use below line

```
console.log(this.fv.value);
```

Comment: Cannot find fv, using hooks

Comment: How you using hooks here ?

Comment: I suggest better to use onChange event rather follow this approach. As React says use onChange event to get values

Answer (score 0):

Assign `ref="password"` to the input itself instead of the `TextField`. Currently you are executing `getValue()` on some abstract (probably some container) tag (`TextField`), not on the `input` itself.

[Here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html)'s how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the input value like this :

> ```
> this.refs.password.input.value;
> ```