# React password masking

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, ecmascript-6, masking

Hello guys I am building a small component that will mimic password masking from mobile devices. Example: "*****4".

Every new character is shown and the rest are masked with a "*".

I have been running into problems with handling the keystrokes.

```
keyCode
```

Does not seems to be reliable some characters are totally different and then I have to do some kind of strange substractions to get the correct code.

Here is what I have till now :

https://codepen.io/kdichev/pen/MpWjQZ

my questions is how would I approach this so I can make it **reliable**

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31446751/how-to-get-password-field-value-in-reacts-material-ui)

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just add an onchange event handler and store the value from event.target.value in some temporary state than when you render the text box give it a modified version of the text stored in state?

Comment: Tyler no particular reason. Its just my reasoning and logic formation. Open to suggestions :) will try this