# Material UI component reference does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am building a little chat application.i have used Material UI TextField to input user message. but i can't refer it. I read about this. they said that they do not support for `refs`. 
this is my code. and it works.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      q: "default"
    };

  }
  handleChanges(val) {
    this.setState({ q: val });
  }
  handleSearch(val) {
    this.setState({ q: val });
    console.log(this.state.q);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>  {this.state.q}</h1>
        <Row className="show-grid">
          <Col sm={2} md={4} className="contact"><h5>contact</h5><br /></Col>
          <Col sm={10} md={8} className="chat grid-border"><h5>chat</h5><br />
            <div className="history"></div>
            <div className="message top-border">

              <input type="text" ref="question" onChange={(e) => { this.handleChanges(this.refs.question.value) }} />
              <MuiThemeProvider>
                <FlatButton label="Primary" primary={true} onTouchTap={(e) => { e.preventDefault(); this.handleSearch(this.refs.question.value); }} />
              </MuiThemeProvider>

            </div>
          </Col>
        </Row>{/*show-grid ends here*/}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

If i used this material UI `TextField` instead of native HTML input tag it does not get the value from the reference.

```
<MuiThemeProvider>
       <TextField hintText="Ask your question" fullWidth={true} multiLine={true} rows={2} rowsMax={4} type="text" ref="question" onChange={(e) => { this.handleChanges(this.refs.question.value) }}/>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

Is there any workaround or alternative UI library for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In onChange method, you don't need to use `ref` to access value of same textfield, material-ui TextField pass 2 parameters in onChange method:

```
event, value
```

So you can write it like this without using ref:

```
<TextField ... onChange={(e, value) =>  this.handleChanges(value) }/>
```

As per [DOC](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field):

> onChange: function
>
> Callback function that is fired when the textfield's value changes.
>
> Signature: function(event: object, newValue: string) => void
>
> event:
> Change event targeting the text field.
>
> newValue: The new value of the
> text field.

Comment: Good solution. If we add another <TextField> element, the same method would not work. Would need to write a duplicate method. Ideally with refs, given ref="a" and ref="b" on 2 TextFields, we could just check this.refs.a.value and this.refs.b.value in the setState method, but this doesn't work with Material UI.

Answer (score 14):

You can also use `inputRef`. This prop is available from material 1.0.

```
<TextField
   className={classes.textField}
   inputRef={input => (this._my_field = input)}
   label="My field"
   fullWidth
   margin="normal"
   defaultValue={this.props.my_field}
   onChange={this.handleChange("dhis_password")}
/>
```

The on change let’s you update the state when it changes, but if you need to get the value unchanged, then the inputRef is necessary.

Also have a look at You can see this [How to get password field value in react's material-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31446751/how-to-get-password-field-value-in-reacts-material-ui/47329368#47329368)

Answer (score 5):

Try the following

```
    let emailRef =React.createRef();
```

in the material-ui input field use `inputRef`

```
 <TextField label="Email Address" name="email" inputRef ={emailRef} />
```

Just use `inputRef` not ref

Answer (score 4):

if you are using a stateless functional component with material ui then you can use react hooks.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

let MyComponent = (props) => {

  let textInput = useRef(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        onClick={() => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            textInput.current.focus();
            textInput.current.click();
            textInput.current.value="myname";
          }, 100);
        }}
      >
        Focus TextField
      </Button>
      <TextField
        fullWidth
        required
        inputRef={textInput}
        name="firstName"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter Your First Name"
        label="First Name"
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 3):

This way of referencing elements is deprecated. See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Try using this:

```
<TextField hintText="Ask your question" fullWidth={true} multiLine={true} rows={2} rowsMax={4} type="text" ref={(input) => { this.input = input; }} onChange={(e) => { this.handleChanges(this.refs.question.value) }}/>
```

And reference the TextField as `this.input`

If you want to get the TextField value, use `this.input.getValue()`

I did something like that [here](https://github.com/darde/RD-Book-Store/blob/dev/src/components/InputSearch/InputSearch.jsx).

Comment: It works, may be something with your code. Can you share your code?

Comment: Hi Adrian, are you using a Class element, or a Pure element? Can you share some fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

This solution allows for multiple TextField elements, accessible by the this.(name) accessible inside the class.

We can still use ref, but have to by passing in a function and adding another property on the class (not on props, refs, or state, but on the class itself). Material UI provides a .getValue() method from which we can retrieve the value.

```
class App extends Component {
...
handleQuestion() {
    this.setState({
        q : this.question.getValue(),
        /** add more key/value pairs for more inputs in same way **/
    })
}
...
<MuiThemeProvider>
   <TextField 
      hintText="Ask your question"
      fullWidth={true} 
      multiLine={true} 
      rows={2} 
      rowsMax={4} 
      type="text" 
      ref={(q) => { this.question = q; }}
      onChange={ this.handleQuestion }
    />
</MuiThemeProvider> 



}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have `TextField` inside `MenuItem`, which is hidden by default, so I can't use the opening menu event, because input field is not yet rendered

The only way works for me is watching variable with DOM element

```
  const [textInput, setTextInput] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (textInput) {
      textInput.focus();
    }
  }, [textInput]);

  return (
    <MenuItem>
      <TextField
        inputRef={setTextInput}
      />
    </MenuItem>
  );
```