# useRef reset textInput by Clicking button

Tags: reactjs, input, material-ui, frontend, reset

i am using material-ui for my project and i am doing function to reset text of input to empty when clicking an outer button, it seem like not worked out

this is my code

```
var inputRef = useRef(null)
```

assign inputRef to the input field to access DOM

```
<TextField label="Student Name" ref={inputRef} />
```

an outer button to reset text field to empty when click it:

```
  <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => {inputRef.current.value = ""}}>
    Reset
  </Button>
```

and it unchanged, if it is possible, please modify the code in the codesandbox link [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/useref-reset-text-input-by-clicking-outer-button-1qwmp), thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You do incorrectly in step: **assign inputRef to the input field to access DOM**. It should be a ref of `input element` instead `text field component` (actual a div).

You should have state for `value` of Textfield Or using `inputRef` instead of `ref` to point to input element. [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/useref-reset-text-input-by-clicking-outer-button-forked-zgcmd?file=/src/App.js)

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { TextField, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  var inputRef = useRef(null);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextField label="Student Name" inputRef={inputRef} />
      <Button
        onClick={() => {
          console.log(inputRef);
          inputRef.current.value = "";
        }}
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
      >
        Reset
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

useRef can be used on html DOM elements(`<input/>`). To pass ref to Material-UI input you should use **inputRef** property.

Please refer [How can I use ref in TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59647940/how-can-i-use-ref-in-textfield)

```
 var inputRef = useRef(null);

<TextField label="Student Name" inputRef={inputRef} />
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/useref-reset-text-input-by-clicking-outer-button-forked-zfpve?file=/src/App.js)