# React native useRef is giving me undefined

Tags: react-native

I am trying to use useRef hook this way.
I want to get the value of textInput with it

```
  let tagsRef = useRef('');



 <TextInput
                ref={tagsRef}
                style={styles.textInputStyle}
                placeholder={'Add tags to subscribe to them'}
                placeholderTextColor={'lightgray'}
              />
            </View>
```

I am using `react-native version:0.63.3`

When I

```
 console.log(----tag', tagsRef.current.focus());
```

It gives me undefined

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Does `focus()` even return something? Its just an action without any result (other than focussing the element). Could you explain what you want to do?

Comment: Try with this answer on [How can I use ref in TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59648972/10415577) question. Is it working for you?

Comment: Current returns a huge object

Comment: I am trying to get the value from textInput, I thought using focus would solve it

Answer (score 1):

Check this its Officially RN Documentation

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

```
function TextInputWithFocusButton() {
  const inputEl = useRef(null);
  const onButtonClick = () => {
    // `current` points to the mounted text input element
    inputEl.current.focus();
  };
  return (
    <>
      <input ref={inputEl} type="text" />
      <button onClick={onButtonClick}>Focus the input</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is depending on where do you use the ref. The ref is only filled after the first rendering. You can use it for instance in an event handler on the element.

Another point: You might see that the `focus` method does not return anything. So when you see an `undefined` in your console, it is properly related to that problem.

But without further context of your code and your problem, it is hard to give a more detailed answer.

Comment: I am trying to get the value of TextInput with it

Comment: In that case, it seems that controlled input are more suited for your application. You can read details about that topic [here in the RN Documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/handling-text-input).